# Phonegap filetransfer timeout

Tags: android, cordova

Is there a way of defining the timeout for a download file transfer in phonegap. On an android device I get the following after 8 minutes if I attempt to download an unresponsive URL:

```
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658): Error getting HTTP status code from connection.
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:516)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.download(FileTransfer.java:495)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:88)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:231)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:131)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
02-05 11:50:38.234 W/FileTransfer(12658):   ... 15 more
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658): {"target":"\/storage\/sdcard0\/Android\/data\/uk.ac.edina.mobile\/cache\/edina\/cache\/open_3_21_37.jpg","source":"http:\/\/fieldtripgb.edina.ac.uk\/mapcache\/tms1.0.0\/fieldtripgb@BNG\/3\/21\/37.jpg?version=1.1.1&id=22362b279a637a91&app=free&cache=true","code":3}
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658): java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:516)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.download(FileTransfer.java:495)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer.execute(FileTransfer.java:88)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at org.apache.cordova.api.PluginManager$1.run(PluginManager.java:231)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:131)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
02-05 11:50:38.234 E/FileTransfer(12658):   ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it is a feature request https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2394

Answer (score 9):

It seems they decided not to implement this as an option, so it leaves the only choice as using `abort()` and `setTimeout()`.

As it seems naive to set an arbitrary time limit on a download/upload, I would reset the timeout from `fileTransfer.onProgress()`

Something like this:

```
var downloadTimer = setTimeout(function () {
    downloadTimerExceeded(fileTransfer);
}, 30000);

fileTransfer.onprogress = function (progressEvent) {
        if (downloadTimer) {
            clearTimeout(downloadTimer); //cancel the previous timer.
            downloadTimer = null;
        }
        downloadTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            downloadTimerExceeded(fileTransfer);
        }, 30000);
};

function downloadTimerExceeded(fileTransfer) {
    fileTransfer.abort();
}
```

It would be much better if they had a timeout option on FileTransfer itself.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using chunkedMode option?

Comment: I assume you refer to the chunkedMode in FileUploadOptions for upload: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileUploadOptions. I'm using download: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download

Answer (score 0):

As said in a feature request comment, this could be done by manipulating abord() with a setTimeout()